# Action Bar has some residual from Progress bar when Progress bar is off

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a circular progress bar at my activity. It works well. But when the progress bar is off, it leaves some residual from the progress bar as shown in the image. I think I need to refresh the progress bar so that I can get back the clean Action Bar again. The first figure is for when the progress bar is running and the second figure is when the progress bar is off (circular arrows are residuals) . My code is as follow. How can I have clean Action Bar again?

(1)airport_menuRefresh.xml in res/menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/airport_menuRefresh"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
         android:title="@string/menuitem_refresh"
         android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
         android:orderInCategory="1"
         android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

(2)actionbar_indeterminate_progress.xml in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:minWidth="50dp">
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="35dp"
       android:layout_height="35dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
     />

</FrameLayout>
```

(3)Menu inflation

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.optionsMenu = menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.airport_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

(4)Method for turning ON/OFF the progress bar

```
public void setRefreshActionButtonState(final boolean refreshing) {
        if (optionsMenu != null) {
            final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu
                .findItem(R.id.airport_menuRefresh);
            if (refreshItem != null) {
                if (refreshing) {
                    refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
                } else {
                    refreshItem.setActionView(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can set `airport_menuRefresh` visibility to off to remove it.
Thanks